# nginx client authentication with multiple client certificates

Tags: ssl, nginx

I am trying to set up a NGINX to perform client authentication against multiple clients. The problem I have is that those clients will have different certificates, basically different Root CAs:

```
[clientA.crt] ClientA > IntermediateA > RootA
[clientB.crt] ClientB > IntermediateB1 > IntermediateB2 > RootB
```

I looked at the NGINX documentation and I noticed the `ssl_client_certificate` directive. However, that property alone seems not work by itself, for example, if I configure it for only work for clientA for now:

```
ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/clientA.crt;   
ssl_verify_client on;
```

Then I received a 400 error code back. By looking at other questions, I figured out that I also have to also use `ssl_verify_depth: 3`. Therefore, if I want concatenate both clientA and clientB in a bundle PEM to allow both clients, will I need use a high value? What's the purpose of this directive and what are the implications of setting to a high number with a bundled PEM?

Comment: What is your use case here? You want to have different client certificate to be able to authenticate against your nginx? Can you explain what final setup are you trying to achieve

Comment: @TarunLalwani I want to have different client certificates to be authenticated against the same NGINX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The http://nginx.org/r/ssl_client_certificate directive is used to specify which certificates you trust for client-based authentication.  Note that the whole list is basically sent every time a connection is attempted (use `ssl_trusted_certificate` as per the docs if that's not desired).

As per above, note that `ssl_verify_depth` basically controls how easy would it be to get into your system — if you set it at a high-enough value, and someone is able to obtain a certificate with one of the CAs that you trust, or through one of their intermediaries which they trust to generate their own certificates, then they'd be able to authenticate with your nginx, whether or not that's your desire.

As such, it'd normally be the practice that all certificates that are used for client-based authentication are generated by a privately sanctioned CA, hence, normally, there shouldn't be much of a length to the chain.  If you want to equalise the depth number between the two CAs, to get the best protection from `ssl_verify_depth`, then it's conceivable to create an extra CA to add to the depth, then that CA to the trusted list instead of what's now an actual intermediary.  (Note that it gets complicated once you involve a few intermediaries, the browser would need to know of their existence, which is usually cached, and can result in a number of ghost issues when non-cached.)

Also, note that you don't actually have to have a single CA in the specified file — it can include multiple unrelated "root" CAs, so, if you want to add multiple independent CAs, you don't actually have to bother creating another CA to certify them — you can just include such independent CAs as-is.

Answer (score 0):

be sure that you use 2 different root certificates with actually different DN, if you are trying this locally with certificates which have the same DN this will not work, as stated by nginx here

https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1871#ticket

We were stuck with this long when I found this old issue also in kubernetes.

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4234